# How to provide Context with Hilt Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger, dagger-hilt

I am trying to migrate a project to Hilt but facing the below issue, not sure how to pass Context with Hilt. If I remove `provideContext` method then it complains with the below error:

```
error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] @dagger.hilt.android.qualifiers.ApplicationContext android.content.Context cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
```

But my understanding is that in Hilt we don't need `provideContext` method and we could just use `@ApplicationContext` like below:

```
@Inject
public CardLayoutManager(@ApplicationContext Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot inject context directly with that annotation. That is reserved for modules.

Comment: Please check the example at https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#java public class AnalyticsServiceImpl implements AnalyticsService {

  private final Context context;

  @Inject
  AnalyticsAdapter(@ApplicationContext Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }
}
So do we still need a provideContext method?

Comment: Have you created a module to provide CardLayoutManager with a scope (ie. SingletonScope)? If yes please share the code

Comment: @AndroidDev Have you found a solution yet? This is driving me insane

Answer (score 12):

You need to annotate the constructor properly:

```kotlin
class CardLayoutManager @Inject constructor(@ApplicationContext val context: Context) {
}
```

Comment: That was a Java class. Even in Kotlin files I'm getting the same error with constructor injection.

Comment: From what I know, wherever you use the Hilt Components, you need your entry class to be annotated with `@AndroidEntryPoint` in order to load the dependencies graph. Is this your case?

Comment: Make sure you remember to include the `val` keyword! I forgot to include it, and once I added it like in your answer my issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the @ApplicationContext annotation

I have read all the documentation more than 5 times, tried the correct method and updated all the Hilt libraries but the problem prevailed.

Once I removed the annotation it all worked perfectly which is strange because I used the correct approach (using the @ApplicationContext annotation) in my other projects.